# Why a re-added file disappears when merging the branch in Git?

Tags: git

In the master branch, I deleted "MyFile" file. Then, I created a new branch and I realized that I needed to add again "MyFile". After some time working in this branch, I merged it to master.

The merge did not add "MyFile" to master, however, it was deleted before the creation of the branch but it was added in the branch. Why? How can I fix it?

Comment: first thing to check: is the commit in which you "readded" the file present on your master branch? check this using `git log`

Answer (score 0):

Probably somthing went wrong in the merging... I suggest you to use

```
git log --stat
```

to track down the commit that removed the file, and if the commit that readded the file is present in your master branch

**EDIT**
better still:

```
git log --stat --follow -- MyFile
```

to see only the commits in which `MyFile` was changed

Comment: @daniel if my answer helped you, please consider accepting it.